# How do I add a .java file using Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

(Noob alert!)

I want to add an SQLite component to a simple (one Java source file) app and would like to put it in a separate file. I was hoping to find something that would let me click a couple check boxes and creae the file using a template with the standard overrides and class declarations (e.g. ... MyClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {...} and so on. Instead I can't even figure out how to add an empty .java file to the project. Google's Android Studio Tips 'n Tricks suggest navigating to the 'appropriate directory in the Project pane' and hit N. That gets me a dialogue that rejects my class name and seems to open a header file if I enter the name if the class I wish to extend (and without apparently adding anything to my project.)

I do not even see a way to add an existing file to the project. OK... I now see that if I create the .java file in the app directory (along side the MainActivity.java file) that Android Studio automatically includes it.

Is this Standard Operating Procedure? It leaves me feeling like I'm not leveraging the capabilities that Android Studio provides.

I'm using AS 0.5.2, openJDK 1.7.0

Thanks!`

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a new Java class from the Project pane, you don't need to add the ".java" to the name; you're specifying the name of the Java class, not the source file. It will figure out the filename automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll probably get in trouble for this but just wanted to say that the 'B' in HankB stands for Barta. Good to hear from another one!